# How to update the groupId of a tab in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

So recently, I began learning how to make extensions in chrome. I was trying to modify one example given in the chrome dev docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/get-started/tutorial/popup-tabs-manager).

I want to modify it so that I can also ungroup tabs which are already grouped if I click on the button again.

I studied the documentation of both [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs) and [tabGroups](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabGroups) to see how this could be done. I decided to use the chrome API `tabs.ungroup` for ungrouping grouped tabs.

```
async function groupTabs(tabIds) {
  const group = await chrome.tabs.group({ tabIds });
  await chrome.tabGroups.update(group, { title: "Docs", collapsed: true, color: "cyan" });
}

async function groupUngroupTabs(tabs) {
  const tabIds = tabs.map(({ id }) => id);

  if (!tabIds.length) {
    return;
  }

  const groupIds = tabs.map(({ groupId }) => groupId);
  if (groupIds.length === 1 && groupIds[0] === chrome.tabGroups.TAB_GROUP_ID_NONE) {
    await groupTabs(tabIds);
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < groupIds.length-1; i++) {
    if (groupIds[i] === chrome.tabGroups.TAB_GROUP_ID_NONE || groupIds[i] !== groupIds[i+1]) {
      await groupTabs(tabIds);
      console.log(tabs.map(({ groupId }) => groupId));
      return;
    } 
  }

  await chrome.tabs.ungroup(tabIds);
}

async function getTabs(urls) {
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({url: urls})

  const collator = new Intl.Collator();
  tabs.sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.title, b.title));
  return tabs;
}

async function setUpHTML(urls) {
  const tabs = await getTabs(urls);
  const template = document.getElementById("li_template");
  const elements = new Set();

  for (const tab of tabs) {
    const element = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);

    const title = tab.title.split("-")[0].trim();
    const pathname = new URL(tab.url).pathname.slice("/docs".length);

    element.querySelector(".title").textContent = title;
    element.querySelector(".pathname").textContent = pathname;
    element.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", async () => {
      await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true });
      await chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, { focused: true });
    });

    elements.add(element);
  }

  document.querySelector("ul").append(...elements);

  const button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", () => groupUngroupTabs(tabs));
}

const urls = [
  "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/*",
  "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/*",
  // "https://*/*",
  // "http://*/*",
];

setUpHTML(urls);
```

The problem is that this works only once. If the tabs are ungrouped, then they will get grouped fine, but clicking again does nothing. Now if I close the extension popup and reopen it and click, the tabs will get ungrouped, but then clicking again won't group them back.

Since the tab group information is stored in `tab.groupId`, I began console logging the `groupId` of the tabs after and before grouping/ungrouping them.

I noticed that grouping/ungrouping them doesn't change the `groupId` of the tabs. I read documentation and was hoping to find something in `tab.update()` but I couldn't find anything.

Interestingly, the `groupId` of the tabs does update, but only after I close the extension. That is why closing and opening the extension works as expected, but obviously I would like to have the functionality without doing that everytime.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me in subsequent runs. Maybe you're trying to group tabs from different windows? How do you obtain `tabs`?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to include the entire code. Essentially, I use
`const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ url: urls })`
here `urls` is a fixed array of urls which is declared near the bottom of the code

Comment: Any idea why it is not working for me? Is it something to do with the way I have queried inside an event handler function or something?

Comment: I guess it might be because you reuse `tabs` in the click listener. I've used your previous code with chrome.tabs.query every time.

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue indeed. It was using the old tabs object even after I clicked the button, so was not registering the `groupId` change